# Compare WP Custom Field date

Tags: custom-field, wp-query, date-time

I had create a custom field "date" with this format 16/09/2013 (d/m/Y).

How can i compare date and show only post with date from today ?

This is my query that don't work !!

```
$args = array(  
'posts_per_page' => 100,    
    'meta_key' => 'date',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',   
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'city',
        'value' => 'London',
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'date',
        'value' => date("Y/m/d"),
'compare' => '>=',
    'type' => 'DATE'
    ),
)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [meta.php:777](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/meta.php#L777):

```
... CAST($alias.meta_value AS {$meta_type}) {$meta_compare} {$meta_compare_string})...
```

So if you want to use DATE comparisons, you should use MySQL compatible date formats (YYYY-MM-DD).

Change this part of your code:

```
array(
    'key' => 'date',
    'value' => date("Y/m/d"),
    'compare' => '>=',
    'type' => 'DATE'
),
```

to:

```
array(
    'key' => 'date',
    'value' => date("Y-m-d"),  // <- change
    'compare' => '>=',
    'type' => 'DATE'
),
```

and it should work just fine.